# pygame multiple removable item

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make collectable and breakable items such as chest, crate, barrel, healt, coin, key in pygame.
Then when interacting with the character; when the character touches it or breaks it, I want it removed.
I can have all the items drawn on the screen as many times as I want, but when I try to remove them, either all or none of them are removed.
This time I tried another approach and used a class, in the for loop I create a class item and add it to the list, and in the main loop I draw the items in the list to the screen. If there is any interference, I remove it from the list. the problem is that when i do this i have serious fps drops.
I could not understand how to solve it and the logic of this work. Sorry if the title or question isn't self-explanatory and I appreciate your help.
My last code;

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640,256))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 32)

map="0b0b0\n11111"
gameMap=[(list(row)) for row in map.split("\n")]

position=(0,0)
barrelList=[]
condition=True

class Barrel:
    def __init__(self,coord):
        self.coord=coord
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("barrel.png"),(64,80))
        self.rect=pygame.Rect((coord[0],coord[1],64,80))
        
    def draw(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.image,self.coord)

while True:
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            position=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
    y=0
    for layer in gameMap:
        x=0
        for tile in layer:
            if tile=="1":#tiles ... etc.
                pygame.draw.rect(surface,"cyan",(x*128,y*128,128,128))
            if tile=="b":#chest, crate, barrel, healt, coin, key ... etc.
                if condition:
                    barrelList.append(Barrel((x*128,y*128)))
                
            x+=1
        y+=1
        
    for barrel in barrelList:
        barrel.draw(surface)
        if barrel.rect.collidepoint(position):
            barrelList.remove(barrel)
            condition=False
    
    surface.blit(font.render("fps:{}".format(int(clock.get_fps())), 1, (255, 255, 255)), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

barrelImage=[image: barrel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is sufficient to create the list of barrels once before the application loop.
2. Remove the barrels in the event loop in case of the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event.
3. See how to [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). Iterate through a shallow copy of the list while removing items:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640,256))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 32)

mapDef = "0b0b0\n11111"
gameMap = [(list(row)) for row in mapDef.split("\n")]
barrelList=[]

class Barrel:
    def __init__(self,coord):
        self.coord=coord
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("barrel.png"),(64,80))
        self.rect=pygame.Rect((coord[0],coord[1],64,80))  
    def draw(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.image,self.coord)

for y, layer in enumerate(gameMap):
    for x, tile in enumerate(layer):
        if tile=="b":#chest, crate, barrel, healt, coin, key ... etc.
            barrelList.append(Barrel((x*128,y*128)))

run = True
while run:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        if ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for barrel in barrelList[:]:
                if barrel.rect.collidepoint(ev.pos):
                    barrelList.remove(barrel)

    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    for y, layer in enumerate(gameMap):
        for x, tile in enumerate(layer):
            if tile=="1":#tiles ... etc.
                pygame.draw.rect(surface,"cyan",(x*128,y*128,128,128))
    for barrel in barrelList:
        barrel.draw(surface)
    surface.blit(font.render("fps:{}".format(int(clock.get_fps())), 1, (255, 255, 255)), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```